# Why does Henry keep his memories during the Black Fairy's curse?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

In "[The Final Battle](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/The_Final_Battle_Part_1)", the two-part Season 6 finale of *Once Upon a Time*, there are two outcomes of the Black Fairy's curse:

- Those who stay in Storybrooke (e.g. Emma, Archie) lose their memories of the last few years
- Those who were transported to the Enchanted Forest kept their memories.

The only exceptions to this were the Black Fairy (who created the curse, so presumably kept herself as a loophole), Rumplestiltskin (who secretly used magic to make himself immune to it), and Henry, all of whom stayed in Storybrooke.

But why did Henry keep his memories yet stay in Storybrooke? The Black Fairy seems surprised to find he is "awake" and has his memories, as well as the *Once Upon a Time* book, which he was not holding at the end of the previous episode. And Rumplestiltskin doesn't indicate that he kept Henry from losing his memories.

So what made Henry immune from the curse? Was it his power as the author?

Comment: *Another* curse. :)

Comment: He's the writer? Just a guess. I have nothing to back me up.

Comment: I'm guessing power as the author or something to do with being born/from the non-magic realm as opposed to any of the story realms like everyone else.

Comment: @JimmyM. Both baby Neal and baby Robin were born in the Land without Magic, but were affected by the curse, although differently than Henry since they went to the Enchanted Forest. Unfortunately, they can't tell us if their memories were intact.

Comment: @thunderforge Yes, but they were both born in Storybrooke, which seems to be an exception to the rest of the Land Without Magic. Just spitting ideas out there

Comment: Henry was holding the book when he woke up, so I just assumed the book protected him.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Unfortunately, he wasn't holding the book during the previous episode's wedding when the curse hit, so it appears to have magically teleported into his hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel it's because he has the Heart of the Truest Believer. When he was ten, he was the only person (excluding Jefferson) who truly believed that everyone in Storybrooke were fairytale characters. It's common for children to believe crazy things, but Henry truly believed it and knew everything in the book was real.

Therefore, Henry's heart is much more pure than expected. Because his heart is so pure, he isn't easily impacted by curses. The reason Emma and the others were affected by the curse was probably because they often felt alone at times or weak. Henry was always looking to prove himself, which protected his heart.

I guess this kind of reflects to Season 7 and that he eventually lost his memories because he finally found a way to prove himself and create his own story.

I don't know, that's just what I feel.

Comment: Sounds like as good an answer as any. Thanks for the late answer!